# SpecFlow 3.0 + .netcore in multi environment

Tags: .net-core, specflow

There is specflow.json in SpecFlow 3 and there is appsetting.json i NetCore 3.0.

I want to run tests with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test?tabs=netcore21 which are depended on environment e.g. integration tests with apis calls.

In .net framework there was app.config and there I could have any appSettings.

How I can do it?